# Error is sbconsole authentication - OSB Console Administration

Tags: authentication, weblogic, osb

After  trying to start the OSB in oracle as root user, I got a lot of problems, one of them is I can access the OSB using the console, I got Authentication denied, but if I try with the WebLogic console is OK, and before that both of them worked perfectly with the same user/password.

Do you have any idea what it might be the error?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Some files got root permissions, and cannot be read now by your WLS user. As root, do a

```
    chown -r wlsuser:wlsgroup YourDomain/
```